# Extensive diacritics input in iOS/iPadOS

Tags: ios, input-source, text-input, ipados

MacOS has an input method known as "ABC - Extended", which allows inputting most diacritics with any Latin letters. With it, "Alt" + various keys give a diacritic waiting to be composed, and pressing a letter produces the letter with the specified diacritic. For example:

Alt + E gives acute (´), which can be used to produce `é` or `ń`

Alt + U gives diaeresis (¨), which can be used to produce `ü` or `ÿ`

Alt + C gives cedilla (¸), which can be used to produce `ş` or `ķ`

Alt + B  and Alt + V give breve (˘) and caron/háček (ˇ) respectively, which can be used to produce Romanian `ă` and Pinyin `ǎ`.

My question: is there a similar way to input various diacritics on iOS/iPadOS? All of the system keyboards seem just to offer a limited set of accented letters.

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to have full coverage of diacritics is to get a hardware keyboard to go with the iOS device.  Then you can just choose ABC Extended as your mapping.

Otherwise you have to search for a 3rd party keyboard (check the [Keyman](https://keyman.com/iphone-and-ipad/) app) or use an app like [Unicode Pad](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/unicode-pad/id374098312).

Comment: THANK YOU. I don't mind using a third-party keyboard at all; that was kind of what I was expecting having to do. But I seriously have no idea how I never noticed you could map hardware keyboard inputs under General - Keyboard - Hardware. Silly of me to have assumed that iOS must _of course_ automatically take care of that for me. It's fantastic not having to choose between hardware/software keyboard and diacritics. Many thanks again! (I've also never realised SIL stood for "_Summer_ Institute of Linguistics" for some reason...kudos to SIL anyway )

Answer (score 0):

In iOS holding the letter down will present a choice of diacritics.

From https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-type-diacritical-marks-on-iphone-ipad/

[image]

Comment: Are Cedilla and Breve  there ?

Comment: Lots of stuff cannot be made this way.  Like it says in the question already "All of the system keyboards seem just to offer a limited set of accented letters."

Comment: Cedilla is available for most but Breve does appear to be missing. It is easy to add a language specific keyboard in iOS. Or as the accepted answer states, use a third-party keyboard.